# Is this compact framework program running on the desktop?

Tags: .net, compact-framework

One of the cool things about the .NET Compact Framework is that you can run .NETCF executables on the desktop version of Windows. However, there are minor incompatibilities between the platforms that have to be dealt with at run-time. My question is, how do I tell which platform I'm on right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.WinCE)
{}
```

I can tell you for a start you'll need this in some GDI+ and also any file access code.